# What is a good circuit model for an AC generator?

Tags: electromagnetism, generator, coil, electric-machine, stator

A very simple electrical AC generator can be made by spinning magnets around a fixed stator coil. The changing magnetic field induces current in the stator winding.

It would seem that at a fixed frequency, this system is best modeled as a current source with some series resistance and inductance. Is this a good model?

If so, it would suggest that the behavior of the system in an open-circuit scenario would be to generate a very high voltage at the output pins with zero current flow. Conversely, in a short circuit scenario, it would run a fixed amount of current through the loop which would be dissipated as heat in the series resistance (stator wires).

Comment: Change in magnetic field induces a voltage as per [Maxwell's equations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations). See the third equation in the table.

Comment: @AJN, so more of a voltage source with series inductance and resistance?

Comment: That seems correct.  Inductance would be larger than resistance.  And since a short-circuit has high voltage over low impedance means large current, which will damage generator.  Same for an AC motor.

Comment: No - it is a VOLTAGE source with series resistance and inductance. A current source would give infinite voltage on no-load.

Comment: Yes, voltage source.  I swear I read voltage source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is generally accepted that synchronous machines are modeled as a sinusoidal voltage source in series with a synchronous reactance, Xs in series with an armature resistance, Ra. A line-to-neutral model of one phase of a three-phase machines is used to analyze a 3-phase machine.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> *It would seem that at a fixed frequency, this system is best modeled
> as a current source with some series resistance and inductance. Is
> this a good model?*

No, that's a very naïve model. A current source in series with anything is still just a current source. A voltage source is made "practical" with series elements (such as R and L) but, a current source is modelled with parallel elements to make it useful.

Comment: C'mon.  It's probably a typo.  The OP meant (or will mean, soon) a **voltage** source with a series impedance, or a current source with a *parallel* impedance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using modeling software that handles mutual inductance, try a mutual pair of inductors and drive one with a sinusoidal voltage.  Use the  other for an output.